# How to build a secret bookcase door in a cased opening?

Tags: doors, flooring, tile, subfloor, studs

I'm looking to build a secret bookcase door to a room that is currently just has cased opening entry.  The opening is roughly 82" x 80" and my thought process would be to have two doors that would both open out since opening in would be over carpet and opening out is over tile and lower.

I think I have most of it figured out except for the flooring...  I have some experience with woodwork in general, but not in a "house construction" sense.  The hinges I plan to use need to be attached at the top and bottom of the opening.  Top should be easy as after ripping off the trim, I'm expecting it to be fairly straightforward to attach it to the stud wall (to be covered with trim again later).  However, the base of the opening is tile and I'm not sure how to proceed here.  The hinge I have is supposed to fasten into the floor, sandwiching itself between the bottom of the door and the floor.  Can I fasten a 2x4 or something similar straight through the tile (there should be typical subfloor below, as this is above the basement)?  Do I need to tear the tile out?  Is it important that whatever board I fasten the hinge to be fastened directly into floor studs?

I'm open to any other ideas as well if there is an easier way to go about this.  I originally thought about using hinges on the side of the door, but I struggled to find any that would be both strong enough and suit the purpose for a hidden book case door.[image: Existing Cased Opening]

Edit: Here's pictures of the instructions for the hinge I want to use:
[image: Hinge 1]
[image: Hinge 1 Zoomed]
[image: Hinge 2]

Comment: There are kits available specifically for this purpose.

Comment: Could you include a picture of the hinge you're going to use? What do the mounting instructions say?

Comment: I've seen a few kits, but I kinda like the fun in DIY'ing it completely (and the kits I saw seemed pretty expensive).  Also added pictures of the instructions for the hinge.